# Prevent Apache for opening files with similar name to url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/generic_oauth$ auth0-callback.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

My vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /home/blabla/www/frontend/
    ServerName some-domain.net
    ServerAlias www.some-domain.net
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/crt/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/crt/key.pem
    <Directory />
              Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Require all granted
     </Directory>
     <Directory /home/blabla/www/>
              Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when I try to access `https://www.some-domain.net/login/generic_oauth` Apache is loading `login.php` (which exists). Problem disappears when I rename the file to `loggin.php` for example.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I try to access `https://www.some-domain.net/login/generic_oauth` Apache is loading `login.php` (which exists). Problem disappears when I rename the file to `loggin.php` for example.

This problem is symptomatic of having MultiViews enabled. Although, you *appear* to be disabling MultiViews in the server config, except that you are not targeting the `DocumentRoot` with your `<Directory>` containers...

> ```
>  DocumentRoot /home/blabla/www/frontend/
>  :
>  <Directory />
>           Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
>           AllowOverride All
>           Require all granted
>  </Directory>
>  <Directory /home/blabla/www/>
>           Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
>           AllowOverride All
>           Require all granted
>  </Directory>
> ```

You should not be setting `AllowOveride All` and `Require all granted` in the `<Directory />` container, ie. the entire drive! You should be disabling access instead and this should already be defined outside of the `<VirtualHost>` container, in the main server config.

You are then granting access to `/home/blabla/www/`, but this is the directory *above* the `DocumentRoot`?! Do you have another `.htaccess` in this parent directory? Do you have another `<Directory>` container that matches the `DocumentRoot`?

So, your config should look more like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName some-domain.net
    ServerAlias www.some-domain.net

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/crt/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/crt/key.pem

    DocumentRoot /home/blabla/www/frontend/

    <Directory /home/blabla/www/frontend>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As with any changes to the server config, you need to restart Apache.

If this does not resolve the issue then you need to look for any other places in the config that could be enabling MultiViews. And if all else fails, explicitly disable MultiViews in the `.htaccess` file itself:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Not working :-( I need to declare urls If I want to work it properly:

`RewriteEngine On
  
RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>

Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/generic_oauth$ auth0-callback.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(dashboard|incidents|security)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`